# Saving high scores is not working for me

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

Im trying to save the highscores, i have 5 textbox for 5 high scores and i want to replace them when they get beaten, obviously. but for me it always goes into the if statement: `if ([hs.text floatValue] == 0)` and it just replaces the fist highscore text box no matter how many times i run it. what am i doing wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        highscore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey: @"highScore"];
        highscore1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey: @"highScore1"];
        highscore2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey: @"highScore2"];
        highscore3 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey: @"highScore3"];
        highscore4 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey: @"highScore4"];

    if ([hs.text floatValue] == 0) {
        hs.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",finTime];
    }
    else if ([hs1.text floatValue] == 0) {
        hs1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",finTime];        
    }
    else if ([hs2.text floatValue] == 0) {
        hs2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",finTime];
    }
    else if ([hs3.text floatValue] == 0) {
        hs3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",finTime];
    }
    else if ([hs4.text floatValue] == 0) {
        hs4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",finTime];
    }
    else if (finTime < highscore) {
        hs4.text = hs3.text;
        hs3.text = hs2.text;
        hs2.text = hs1.text;
        hs1.text = hs.text;
        hs.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",finTime];
    }
    else if (finTime < highscore1) {
        hs4.text = hs3.text;
        hs3.text = hs2.text;
        hs2.text = hs1.text;
    }
    else if (finTime < highscore2) {
        hs4.text = hs3.text;
        hs3.text = hs2.text;
        hs2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",finTime];
    }
    else if (finTime < highscore3) {
        hs4.text = hs3.text;
        hs3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",finTime];
    }
    else if (finTime < highscore4) {
        hs4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f",finTime];
    }
    [self saveScore];
}

-(void) saveScore
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setFloat:finTime forKey:@"highScore"];
    [defaults setFloat:finTime forKey:@"highScore1"];
    [defaults setFloat:finTime forKey:@"highScore2"];
    [defaults setFloat:finTime forKey:@"highScore3"];
    [defaults setFloat:finTime forKey:@"highScore4"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

Comment: Can you include where `hs.text` gets set?

Comment: Is `hs` not `nil`? Has text been put into the text field already? It seems strange that you expect `hs.text` to have some text in it so early in `viewDidLoad`. If there is no text, or if the text isn't a number, or if `hs` is `nil`, you will get a `floatValue` of `0`.

Comment: hs.text gets set in the first if statement. I tried the hs.text == nil and if i do that it doesnt go into the if statement

Comment: What, in English, is your goal here? Do wish to set `hs.text` to `finTime` only if there is no text currently in `hs.text`? If so, do `if (hs.text.length == 0) {`.

Comment: arent strings array of chars with a null char at the en of the array, if so wouldn't it be 1 instead of 0?

Comment: C-strings are arrays of chars with a null terminator. But you are working with `NSString` objects. They are not the same thing. See the docs for `NSString`. Though even with C-strings, a string with just the null terminator has a length of 0, not 1. The null terminator is not counted in the length (see the docs for `strlen`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `hs.text` will not be set (or will be set to 0 if you did that in the xib/Storyboard) when `viewDidLoad` gets called. Because of that, it always goes into the first if statement and you do not use the values stored in `NSUserDefaults`.

I would suggest setting the text fields as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  highscore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey: @"highScore"];
  highscore1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey: @"highScore1"];
  highscore2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey: @"highScore2"];
  highscore3 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey: @"highScore3"];
  highscore4 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey: @"highScore4"];

  if (highscore)
    hs.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f", highscore];
  if (highscore1)
    hs1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f", highscore1];
  if (highscore2)
    hs2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f", highscore2];
  if (highscore3)
    hs3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f", highscore3];
  if (highscore4)
    hs4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.4f", highscore4];

  ...
```

Also, I don't think that the `saveScore` method is working properly, as it sets all the highscores to `finTime`. You probably want to set them to the float values from each of the `hs` text fields.

Comment: this isn't working, its setting the score to all the high scores

Comment: That should be because you've already set all the highScore keys in NSUserDefaults to finTime. Try uninstalling the app and running it again.

Comment: no because every time it replaces the score with the new one, no matter if its better or worste

Comment: Did you remove the rest of the code you had written in viewDidLoad or is it still there?

Comment: Add it back in, that's what I meant by "..." in the answer. Then uninstall the app to clear the NSUserDefaults and try it again.

Comment: the first time it sets the score to all the highscores, then if i beat that high score, it sets the new high score to highscore 1 and the last highs core to high score 2 to 5, then if i dont beat it it stays the same then if i beat it again it sets the new high score to 1 and replaces the high scores 2 to 5 with the last score i made